# Create a contact form and display submissions as searchable directory

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a directory that users can submit their data (name, email, phone) to and see a searchable directory. Ninja Forms was good for submitting data, but had no (free) option to display the data in a searchable format. I tried using Contact Form DB, but the displayed results weren't searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gravity Forms plugin has an API that will allow you to access submitted data. Here is a similar query to your own:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82791/how-do-i-show-data-from-gravity-forms-in-my-template

That said, it would probably be just as easy (if not easier) to code this outside the WordPress framework. Create a new table in the database for user data, then create the corresponding form and PHP form handler to write the details to the table.

WordPress provides a class for explicitly accessing the database:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

You would then simply add your search code into a page template. I hope this helps!

Comment: I saw that Gravity Forms and Ninja Forms have add-ons that will help my cause, but both cost money. 

It looks like I might just build a form and database on my own, of which I have no idea how to do. However, I'm looking forward to learning. Thanks for the help.